# What does "SCM" in "Maven SCM Plugin" stands for?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have checked the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/index.html) of Maven SCM Plugin, and the SCM is always used only as abbreviation, but they never describe what does this abbreviation mean.

So what does it mean?

Comment: SCM stands for Source Code Management and the plugin provides integrations for different SCM systems like git or subversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well from the [index page](https://maven.apache.org/scm/index.html) of its official website , it mentions :

> Maven SCM supports Maven plugins (for example maven-release-plugin)
> and other tools by providing them with a common API for **source code**
> **management** operations.

And then from [here](https://maven.apache.org/scm/scms-overview.html) , it mentions the following SCM are fully supported :

- Git
- Mercurial
- Subversion
- Local

And also mentions the following SCM are deprecated at [here](https://maven.apache.org/scm/index.html) :

- accurev
- bazaar
- clearcase
- integrity
- jazz
- perforce
- starteam
- synergy
- tfs
- vss
- cvs

Since all of them are source code version control system , we can deduce that SCM is the abbreviation for **s**ource **c**ode **m**anagement

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful:

https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#scm

> SCM (Software Configuration Management, also called Source Code/Control Management or, succinctly, version control)